# Lightbox like a popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, autoplay

This code is a lightbox, but it's necessary click to show the content, and I need it appearing without click. Automatic. Kind a pop up.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.lightbox').click(function() {
    $('.background, .box').animate({
      'opacity': '.60'
    }, 500, 'linear');
    $('.box').animate({
      'opacity': '1.00'
    }, 500, 'linear');
    $('.background, .box').css('display', 'block');
  });

  $('.close').click(function() {
    $('.background, .box').animate({
      'opacity': '0'
    }, 500, 'linear', function() {
      $('.background, .box').css('display', 'none');
    });;
  });

  $('.background').click(function() {
    $('.background, .box').animate({
      'opacity': '0'
    }, 500, 'linear', function() {
      $('.background, .box').css('display', 'none');
    });;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How's this?  Move code into functions and then just run open popup function on document ready:

```html
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.lightbox').click(function() {
    openPopup();
  });

  $('.close').click(function() {
    closePopup();
  });

  $('.background').click(function() {
    closePopup();
  });

   openPopup();
});


function openPopup() {
    $('.background, .box').animate({
      'opacity': '.60'
    }, 500, 'linear');
    $('.box').animate({
      'opacity': '1.00'
    }, 500, 'linear');
    $('.background, .box').css('display', 'block');
}

function closePopup() {
    $('.background, .box').animate({
      'opacity': '0'
    }, 500, 'linear', function() {
      $('.background, .box').css('display', 'none');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger an event using Jquery. If you want this pop up to open automatically then use
 $('.lightbox').trigger("click")
in document.ready function. This will automatically call that class click and by this your light box pop up will open.